# Ruby: hash not OK to be sorted

Tags: ruby

My hash is grumpy. :(

I want to sort it but it doesn't want, and I can't find the reason of it:

```
x = [{2 => "two", 1 => "one"}, {4 => "four", 3 => "three"}]

x.each do |y|
    if y.is_a?(Hash) then y = y.sort end
end
```

(the hash has to be sorted in a .each method)

In the end, instead of having this structure:

```
[{2=>"two", 1=>"one"}, {4=>"four", 3=>"three"}]
```

I want this structure:

```
[[[1, "one"], [2, "two"]], [[3, "three"], [4, "four"]]]
```

After reading some similar questions I tried to replace `Hash` by `::Hash` or convert the hash into an array before sorting it but it still doesn't work...

How can I sort my hash?

Comment: How do you want to sort. Which you would like to be the result?

Comment: Instead of having this structure:
[{1=>"one", 2=>"two"}, {3=>"three", 4=>"four"}]

I want this structure:
[[[1, "one"], [2, "two"]], [[3, "three"], [4, "four"]]]

Comment: Your example does not require any sorting. If sorting may be needed explain what the desired sorting order is (both for the order of the hashes in the array and the order of the key-value pairs within each hash, before being converted to arrays) and (especially) change the array of hashes in the example so that it is not in the desired sorted order.

Comment: YES MY LORD I'M AT YOUR SERVICE

Comment: Why do you want to sort a hash? Sort the keys however you want and extract the values using `values_at`. "The hash has to be sorted in an `.each` method"? Why? Is this a class assignment that you want us to solve for you?

Comment: Well, your hash is sorted, you just don't do anything with that sorted hash apart from assigning it to a local variable which immediately goes out of scope.

Comment: I see that you never accept answers. Maybe best go through all of your questions and accept the correct answer with the checkmark.

Comment: @akuhn I read every answer and grab every help people want to give me, and I do my best to understand all I can. thx for the advice btw

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = [{2=>"two", 1=>"one"}, {4=>"four", 3=> "three"}]

arr.map { |h| h.sort_by(&:first) }
  #=> [[[1, "one"], [2, "two"]], [[3, "three"], [4, "four"]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is grumpy not your hash :)

You are sorting the hash, but your loop does not update the array.

Here is a simplified example

```
array.each do |y|
  y = y.sort  
end
```

Above reassigns the sorted hash to the local variable `y` and does thus not update the value in `array`. Assignment to the block parameter does not write back to the array that you are enumerating over.

Use `map` instead

```
array = array.map do |y|
  y.sort  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of **Cary Swoveland** is the short one

here I write a longer version

```
x = [{ 2 => "two", 1 => "one"}, {4 => "four", 3 => "three"}]
y = x.map{ |el| el.to_a.sort }
```

so the variables should be like

```
 x => [{ 2 => "two", 1 => "one"}, {4 => "four", 3 => "three"}]
 y => [[[1, "one"], [2, "two"]], [[3, "three"], [4, "four"]]]
```